# Password input may be echoed when run Python Fabric command in crontab

Tags: python, python-2.7, fabric

I encountered issue when trying to run my program through crontab on Mac OS. My program works fine when run it independently. Normally, I never set env.password for remote system password. For instead, I set env.key_filename. It works fine if i don't have to run sudo command. So ideally, it shouldn't prompt any password typing.

By referring to https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1230, i also tried to set environment variables to pass the password. Yet, i still get the same error. What did i miss? Anyone can help pls?

Thx

## Error msg:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/getpass.py:83: GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
  passwd = fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Login password for 'xxx': [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Executing task 'System.Monitor.free_mem'

[+] Start checking system total/free memory in MB:
[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] run: free -m
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 757, in main
    *args, **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 386, in execute
    multiprocessing
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 276, in _execute
    return task.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 173, in run
    return self.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/thomas.pan/Python-ninja/playwith/DevOps/System/Monitor.py", line 69, in free_mem
    run("free -m")
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 687, in host_prompting_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 1090, in run
    shell_escape=shell_escape, capture_buffer_size=capture_buffer_size,
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 930, in _run_command
    channel=default_channel(), command=wrapped_command, pty=pty,
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/state.py", line 424, in default_channel
    chan = _open_session()
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/state.py", line 416, in _open_session
    return connections[env.host_string].get_transport().open_session()
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 159, in __getitem__
    self.connect(key)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 151, in connect
    user, host, port, cache=self, seek_gateway=seek_gateway)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 569, in connect
    password = prompt_for_password(text)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 652, in prompt_for_password
    new_password = _password_prompt(password_prompt, stream)
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 624, in _password_prompt
    return getpass.getpass(prompt.encode('ascii', 'ignore'), stream)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/getpass.py", line 83, in unix_getpass
    passwd = fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/getpass.py", line 118, in fallback_getpass
    return _raw_input(prompt, stream)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/getpass.py", line 135, in _raw_input
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Comment: Issue closed by switch to launchd with LaunchControl tool. It's not Fabric issue.

Comment: you can post your solution as an answer and accept it by yourself

Answer (score 0):

Issue closed by switch to launchd with LaunchControl tool. It's not Fabric issue.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone - if you're running a command that is logging into an instance, this GetPassWarning/OEFError issue can happen with a cron job, since the shell session does not know how to log into that instance.

To fix this, you may need to give ssh context to crond. [ssh-cron](https://gitlab.com/fbb-git/ssh-cron) can do this, for example, since it looks like there is difficulty getting that all set up in crontab.